Access denied with Kerberos Delegation in IIS-hosted ASP.NET web application when accessing shared folder on another server
How can I resolve the "Access Denied" issue when accessing a shared folder on SERVER03 from an IIS-hosted ASP.NET application using Kerberos delegation, despite having configured the service account (svc_iis) and SPNs correctly?
Detailed Context:
I am working on a setup with the following machines:

WS01: Client machine
DC01: Domain controller (manages users, SPNs, delegation settings)
SERVER02: IIS server running Visual Studio IDE
SERVER03: File server with a shared folder

All machines are joined to the same domain (CONTOSO.LOCAL), with static IPs.
Setup Overview:

Service Account (svc_iis):

Has correct SPNs configured: HTTP/file and HTTP/file.contoso.local.
Has "Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)" set up in Active Directory.
Full control permissions on C:\inetpub\wwwroot on SERVER02.


IIS Configuration:

IIS server on SERVER02 hosts a simple ASP.NET Web Application.
Application uses Windows Authentication and impersonates the authenticated user.
In Web.config, I have the following settings:



<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />

Web Application:
In my web application, I have a simple ListFiles.aspx page which attempts to list files from the shared folder on SERVER03.

Code for ListFiles.aspx.cs:

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class ListFiles : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string networkPath = @"\\server03.contoso.local\test";
            try
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(networkPath);
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    Response.Write($"<p>{file}</p>");
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                Response.Write($"{ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}


Web.config setup:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <identity impersonate="true" />
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
</configuration>


The shared folder (\\server03.contoso.local\test) on SERVER03 has the necessary permissions set for CONTOSO\Domain Users with read access.

The Issue:
When I attempt to access the page at http://file.contoso.local/ListFiles.aspx on WS01, I get an "Access Denied" error after entering my credentials.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Alternatives tested:

Alternative 1: I tested replacing the shared folder on SERVER03 with one on SERVER02. It worked, which indicates that the issue is likely with delegation to SERVER03.
Alternative 2: I modified the Web.config to impersonate the contoso\Administrator account:



<identity impersonate="true" userName="contoso\Administrator" password="****" />

This worked, but obviously doesn't use Kerberos delegation, which is the goal.

Kerberos Analysis:

I captured the Kerberos traffic using Wireshark. The first TGS-REQ (for server02$) completes successfully. However, the second TGS-REQ (for cifs/server03.contoso.local) fails with the error:



krb-error
    pvno: 5
    msg-type: krb-error (30)
    stime: Dec  6, 2024 16:42:34.000000000 Romance Standard Time
    susec: 781312
    error-code: eRR-BADOPTION (13)
    realm: CONTOSO.LOCAL
    sname
        name-type: kRB5-NT-SRV-INST (2)
        sname-string: 2 items
            SNameString: cifs
            SNameString: server03.contoso.local
    e-data: 3015a103020103a20e040c250200c00000000003000000 pA-PW-SALT


This indicates a potential issue with the SPN registration for cifs/server03.contoso.local.


Checking SPNs:

I ran the following command on the domain controller:



PS C:\Users\Administrator> setspn -Q cifs/server03.contoso.local

Output:
Checking domain DC=contoso,DC=local

CN=SERVER03,CN=Computers,DC=contoso,DC=local
    cifs/server03.contoso.local
    cifs/server03
    WSMAN/SERVER03
    WSMAN/SERVER03.contoso.local
    RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER03
    HOST/SERVER03
    RestrictedKrbHost/SERVER03.contoso.local
    HOST/SERVER03.contoso.local

Existing SPN found!

Despite the SPNs showing as present, the error persists.
What I Need Help With:

The Kerberos error eRR-BADOPTION (13) suggests there might be an issue with the SPN for cifs/server03.contoso.local. However, setspn shows that the SPN exists. Could there be an issue with the SPN not being properly registered or propagated across the domain?
How do I resolve the "Access Denied" issue when trying to access the shared folder on SERVER03 from the IIS server on SERVER02, with Kerberos delegation enabled?
Is there something missing in the configuration, particularly related to the SPN or delegation settings? Would re-registering the SPN or adjusting the delegation settings help?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

This setup isn't quite correct. "Service Account (svc_iis): Has correct SPNs configured: HTTP/file and HTTP/file.contoso.local." It's the SERVER02 machine account that needs the SPNs. And that would only work if file.contoso.local is being used in the HTTP request, otherwise you need SERVER02.contoso.local. Also "Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)" is an exceedingly risky idea, you should set up Constrained Delegation (or Resource Based Constrained Delegation) instead. Also any sort of delegation won't work at all with Protected Users (includes Domain Admins)

Also ensure you are using the FQDN not just the server name everywhere

Have you trusted the servers for delegation too? Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/appv-v4/how-to-configure-the-server-to-be-trusted-for-delegation

Hello! Thank you for your response. Yes, I have configured unconstrained delegation for the svc_iis account, which is the identity of the Application Pool. However, for the servers (SERVER02 and SERVER03), the Delegation tab is set to "No Delegation" by default.

[UPDATE] I have configured unconstrained delegation for the svc_iis account, as well as for the SERVER02 and SERVER03 computers. Unfortunately, the "Access Denied" issue persists.
